# Python Agglomerative Clustering

Tags: python-2.7, hierarchical-clustering

I am new on clustering ( using sklearn in Python). I am trying to import Agglomerative Clustering using:

```
from sklearn.cluster import AgglomerativeClustering
```

but I get the following error:

```
from sklearn.cluster import AgglomerativeClustering

ImportError: cannot import name AgglomerativeClustering
```

I did install the latest version of sklearn on my UBUNTU machine from http://scikit-learn.org/, but still no luck!! Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: What do you see when you do `import sklearn.cluster; print dir(sklearn.cluster)` ?

Comment: Could you please explain more what you mean by "print dir(sklearn.cluster)"? I have installed eclips on UBUNTU and I have :


from sklearn.cluster import AgglomerativeClustering

and Iget the following error in concole:

from sklearn.cluster import AgglomerativeClustering
ImportError: cannot import name AgglomerativeClustering

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit late in posting this but for everyone else who comes across this error, you would want to see this thread [Why can't I import the AgglomerativeClustering class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32219881/why-cant-i-import-the-agglomerativeclustering-class)

You probably need to upgrade your scikit-learn version to make use of agglomerative clustering feature.