# Why can't I import the AgglomerativeClustering class?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, importerror

I would like to use [AgglomerativeClustering](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.AgglomerativeClustering.html#sklearn.cluster.AgglomerativeClustering) from sklearn but I am not able to import it.

```
>>> from sklearn.cluster import AgglomerativeClustering
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name AgglomerativeClustering
```

The message dosen't give much information on what's causing the issue, can you help?

---

Python version

```
Python 2.7.6 (default, Jun 22 2015, 17:58:13) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
```

OS info:

```
3.13.0-55-generic #94-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jun 18 00:27:10 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Scikit-learn version

```
$ pip freeze | grep scikit-learn
scikit-learn==0.14.1
```

Further infos

```
>>> import sklearn.cluster; print(sklearn.cluster.__file__)
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/cluster/__init__.pyc
```

Comment: Have you already tried reinstalling scikit-learn? If the library is installed correctly, the import should not fail. Can you include your OS and how you installed scikit-learn?

Comment: It says that in your installation there's no `AgglomerativeClustering` class in that module...  Are you sure that you are using a version that provides it?

Comment: Could you also do this: `import sklearn.cluster; print(sklearn.cluster.__file__)`? Be sure that the output is the path to your installation. If you have a different `sklearn` package installed (maybe one you wrote) it could be imported instead of the package you installed globally.

Comment: @cel: I added the requested infos to the question

Comment: @Bakuriu Added the infos to the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the [changelog for version 0.15](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/whats_new.html#changes-0-15) it looks like the `AgglomerativeClustering` class was introduced in this version:

> ## Changelog
>
> ### New Features
>
> [...]
>
> - Added `cluster.AgglomerativeClustering` for hierarchical agglomerative clustering with average linkage, complete linkage and
>     ward strategies. [...]

So the only fix is to install a newer version of `sklearn`.